# How to search keywords (separated by semicolon) by a given string (separated by semicolon) in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm thinking of using painless script, but it's too much complicated, is there any simple way ?

---

Say I have docs like this :

```
{'id': 1, 'keywords': '21;34;50' ...},
{'id': 2, 'keywords': '1;2;3' ...},
...
```

with a given string `'1;5'`

How can I filter the doc contains keywords `1` or `5` (not `21`, `50` or others) ?

Many thanks！

Comment: i will suggest to use ingest_pipeline rpocessor where you will split your value using semi colon and stored into same field or new field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom analyzer to tokenize on semicolon. For instance, you can define it as following (not tested)

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": { 
          "tokenizer": "punctuation"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "punctuation": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "[;]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More information on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html